# Issue migrating an Objective-C iOS app to a self-hosted Parse-Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-server

On my way moving an Objective-C iOS app from Parse.com to a self-hosted Parse-Server.

I am reading [this document](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-Server-Guide#using-parse-sdks-with-parse-server).

```
    [Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration
                                        configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
        configuration.applicationId = @"MY_APP_ID";
        configuration.clientKey = @"";
        configuration.server = @"https://my_app.herokuapp.com/parse";
    }]];
```

But the problem is that when I use this code, I get this error message:

```
.....] Reachability Flag Status: WR t------ networkStatusForFlags
.....] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ''clientKey' should not be nil.'
```

Does anyone know what to do here?

Comment: was your migration successful using mongo URL?

Comment: Which parse ios SDK version you are using  ?

Comment: Yes as far as I can see the migration successful using mongo URL.
I was using an old version of Parse SDK, and read somewhere this was the issue here. I am now trying to install a new version.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to include the server and applicationID once you are on parse-server. The clientkey is no longer needed, simply do not included it at all.

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration
                                    configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
    configuration.applicationId = @"MY_APP_ID";
//        configuration.clientKey = @""; 
    configuration.server = @"https://my_app.herokuapp.com/parse";
}]];
```